# Array_slice in multidimensional array? But a different output

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, slice

I have an array in php like this :

```
     $multid_array = array(
        "url" => "www.checkmyhouse.cpm",
        "date" => "2019/12/12",
        "minor" => 1,
        "sittingroom" => 1,
        "dinningroom" => 2,
        "toilet" => 2,
        "parking" => 1,
        "bedroom" => 2,
        "garage" => 2,
        "rooms" => 4,
        "garden" => 1,

        "url_1" => "-sameurl-",
        "date_1" => "2019/12/3",
        "minor_1" => 3,
        "sittingroom_1" => 2,
        "dinningroom_1" => 2,
        "toilet_1" => 3,
        "parking_1" => 1,
        "bedroom_1" => 2,
        "garage_1" => 6,
        "rooms_1" => 6,
        "garden_1" => 1,

        "url_2" => "-sameurl-",
        "date_2" => "2019/12/5",
        "minor_2" => 3,
        "sittingroom_2" => 2,
        "dinningroom_2" => 2,
        "toilet_2" => 3,
        "parking_2" => 1,
        "bedroom_2" => 5,
        "garage_2" => 6,
        "rooms_2" => 9,
        "garden_2" => 1,
    );
```

I have searched around, found this link. but not been able to figure it out. keep getting close. 
[array_slice in multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837236/array-slice-in-multidimensional-array)

This is the output I would like:

```
$array =
    [ 
       "levels" => array(
            "0" => array(
                "url" => "www.checkmyhouse.cpm",
                "date" => "2019/12/1",
                "minor" => 1,
                "sittingroom" => 1,
                "dinningroom" => 2,
                "toilet" => 2,
                "parking" => 1,
                "bedroom" => 2,
                "garage" => 2,
                "rooms" => 5,
                "garden" => 1,
            ),
            "1" => array(
                "url" => "-sameurl-",
                "date" => "2019/12/3",
                "minor" => 3,
                "sittingroom" => 2,
                "dinningroom" => 2,
                "toilet" => 3,
                "parking" => 1,
                "bedroom" => 2,
                "garage" => 6,
                "rooms" => 6,
                "garden" => 1,
            ),
            "2" => array(
                "url" => "-sameurl-",
                "date" => "2019/12/5",
                "minor" => 3,
                "sittingroom" => 2,
                "dinningroom" => 2,
                "toilet" => 3,
                "parking" => 1,
                "bedroom" => 5,
                "garage" => 6,
                "rooms" => 9,
                "garden" => 1,
            )
        )
    ];
```

Just trying to rearrange it. but I have used array_slice and could only get the output of the first 9 elements.

```
array_splice($multid_array,9);
```

But I want to run it automatically, so in case more information gets added into the array then it would still work

Comment: You could look at `array_chunk()`, but don't think there is anything which will automatically deal with removing the _1 in `"url_1"` etc.

Comment: Thank you @NigelRen. Used array_chunk() but had to remove the "url_1" _1 completely and let the system count itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use simple for loop: (in this case you can have various number of field in each array and they don't need to be fixed as when use `array_chunk`)

```
$multid_array = array("url" => "www.checkmyhouse.cpm","date" => "2019/12/12","url_1" => "-sameurl-","date_1" => "2019/12/3","url_2" => "-sameurl-","date_2" => "2019/12/5",);

$ans = [];
foreach($multid_array as $k => $v) {
    $parts = explode("_", $k); 
    $pk = 0; //default as 0 as when no prefix set to key "0"
    if (count($parts) > 1) { // check if has suffix
        $pk = $parts[1];
        $k = $parts[0];
    }
    if (!isset($ans[$pk]))
        $ans[$pk] = []; // init array if first time
    $ans[$pk][$k] = $v;
}
```

Now `$ans` will contain your data - you can add "levels" key if you wish.

This will only works if you have "`_`" saved to mark inner indexes and they are not used in the actual keys