# array_slice percentage of multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an interesting problem. I have a multidimensional array like this one:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 4
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 3
            [5] => 3
            [6] => 3
            [7] => 2
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 4
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 3
            [4] => 2
        )
)
```

I'd like to be able to use array_slice to remove a percentage of the rows from each sub array.

As per a previous post here ([array_slice in multidimensional array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837236/array-slice-in-multidimensional-array)), I can remove a fixed number of rows easily enough. But say I wanted to remove 70% of each sub array, which has a varying number of rows, I'm a little bit stuck.

Comment: If you're looping through each sub array as `$sub_array`, you can set the offset (second argument) to 70% of `count($sub_array)` to keep only the last 30%, or set the offset to 0 and set the limit (third argument) to 30% of the same `count` to keep only the first 30% and drop the last 70%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like....

```
<?php

$items = array ( 
        array ( 1, 7, 23, 32, 64, 77 ), 
        array ( 23, 32, 64, 77 ), 
        array ( 1, 5, 7, 13, 16, 23, 32, 64, 77 )
        );

// (?), remove, or keep

$type = 'remove';

// percentage (%)

$percent = 60;

$format = $type == 'remove' ? ( 100 - $percent ) : $percent;

foreach ( $items AS $array => $values )
{
    $max = round ( ( ( count ( $values ) * $format ) / 100 ) );

    $items[$array] = array_slice ( $values, 0, $max );
}

print_r ( $items );

?>
```